# Find the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{x=n}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation

Find the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{x=n}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3}$. Im having issues understanding how to prove this since I have never done something like this. I want to say it goes to zero since I know the series itself converges meaning it also tends to zero. Since x scales with n, once n is sufficiently large the sum would also essentially be 0 is my thinking. I am just unsure of how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: "Converges" does not mean "tends to zero"...

Comment: Your intuition is correct in that the limit is zero. There are many ways of showing it like 1) apply the Cauchy criterion for convergence to the partial sums (gives the result for all convergent series) 2) estimate an upper bound to the sum with an integral (like in the integral test - this works for this series in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that a series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$ converges, then you can write
$$\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n$$

Taking limits on both sides we have $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n - \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} a_n =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 0$$

Comment: That's much easier than my idea I gotta admit...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct: From the fact that a convergent sequence is also a Cauchy sequence we can conclude that the partial sums of the given series also has to be cauchy. Let
$$S_n = \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{x^3}$$
then since we know that $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3}$ converges (meaning the sequence $(S_n)_n$ converges for $n \to \infty$) we know that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exist sufficiently large $n,m \in \mathbb N$ where (WLOG) $n \leq m$:
$$|S_n-S_m| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\sum_{x=n+1}^m \frac{1}{x^3}| < \epsilon$$
In this expression we can use that all the components are positive, so $|\sum_{x=n+1}^m \frac{1}{x^3}| = \sum_{x=n+1}^m \frac{1}{x^3} < \epsilon$ and by letting $m$ tend to $\infty$ (since this inequality holds true for all $n,m$ sufficiently large, it doesn't matter if $n$ and $m$ are close to one another) we obtain
$$\epsilon \ge \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{x=n+1}^m \frac{1}{x^3} = \sum_{x=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3}$$
for sufficiently large $n$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was chosen arbitrarily we get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{x=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^3} =0$$
which means the statement is true.